# Change stacking order in Bootstrap BUT preserve full width on both mobile and desktop?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've looked this question up before but most people usually want to go from desktop:

[B][A]

to (on mobile):

[A]

[B]

And so they do this:

```
           <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
                    A
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
                    B
                </div>
            </div>


       </div> <!-- cointainer -->
```

But I actually want to do (desktop):

[B]

[A]

to mobile:

[A]

[B]

I tried adding things like offset-lg and col-lg-12  but for some reason it makes one of the divs disappear:

```
           <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-lg-offset-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
                    A
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
                    B
                </div>
            </div>


       </div> <!-- cointainer -->
```

Thank you!

Edit:

Trying to accomplish this without duplicating A or B.

Answer (score 0):

**John Tomson**, Hi there. Here is one way to do this just with Bootstrap and making use of the `hidden-xx` classes.
Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/xpbnbvzz/)** for this demo.

This demo code also has the div blocks stacked like you are looking for here.

Just setting up 3 divs  and having two of these divs with the same content and show/hide 1 of these 2 divs when needed is how we are working this example here.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.block {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkorange; 
}  
.block2 {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  margin-top: 2%;  
  margin-bottom: 2%;
      
} 
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;  
}
    
@media(max-width:768px) {
.xs-view {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}    
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container col-lg-12"><br><br></div>
    
    <div class="container col-lg-12">

        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 block">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center block2 hidden-xs xs-view ">
                <h3>B</h3>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center block2 xs-view">
                <h3>A</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-4 text-center block2 hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md xs-view">
                <h3>B</h3>
            </div>      
        </div>
         
    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**Added to this post**

Here is a couple of examples in this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/ab2kbky6/)**.

The 2nd option uses the **Push/Pull**, but it seems to have a limit where it can be only used up to 50% of the width before it breaks.
This 2nd option also uses the `margin-top` to move the div **A** down to allow **B** up.

You can see in the image below that the 2nd option is stacked vertically and using push/pull from the start... with some margin-top help.

The 3rd option uses +/- margin-top here to move **A** down and **B** up.
I always thought there was an issue re cross browser support for using negative value like this, but it looks like I may be wrong going by this **[article](http://www.bloggerever.com/2015/02/negative-margin-css-myth.html)**. (dated 2015)

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I was probably not clear enough. Sorry, I should have been more explicit. Wanted to accomplish this without duplicating one of the divs. It seems like in this solution I would have to duplicate B?

Comment: Hi John, no problem, I first thought you didn't want to use push/pull. I have added to my post with 2 more options.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution for this is actually a little jQuery:

```
if ($(window).width() < 767) {
   $("#b").insertBefore("#a");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 bg-warning" id="a">A</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 bg-danger" id="b">B</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rohv33cd/

Comment: You'll need to handle the case when the browser is resized back to desktop

Comment: Possibly, in which case it's slightly different jquery. You offering a solution?

Comment: Basicly I had the similar problem and solution was to duplicate the element on the page using JS on load in a container. Then show/hide the element based on the breakpoint using Bootstrap classes.